# How to import SubRequest (pytest)?

Tags: python, pytest

In the following code, the request has the type of `<class '_pytest.fixtures.SubRequest'>`. I want to add type hint to the parameter request.

```
@pytest.fixture
def dlv_service(request: SubRequest):  # How to import SubRequest?
    print(type(request), request)
    filepath = pathlib.Path(request.node.fspath.strpath)
    f = filepath.with_name("file.json")
```

The following import doesn't work.

```
from pytest.fixtures import SubRequest
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found one on the internet, hope this will help.

```py
from _pytest.fixtures import SubRequest
```

I think it's worth trying, but not sure whether it could work, sorry.

Answer (score 4):

For some applications, such as accessing the `node` property, you can import `FixtureRequest`, which is part of the public API and a superclass of `SubRequest`. See yourself:

```py
from _pytest.fixtures import SubRequest
from pytest import FixtureRequest
issubclass(SubRequest, FixtureRequest)
hasattr(FixtureRequest, "node")
```

Applying this to your example:

```py
from pathlib import Path

import pytest
from pytest import FixtureRequest


@pytest.fixture
def dlv_service(request: FixtureRequest) -> Path:
    print(type(request), request)
    filepath = Path(request.node.fspath.strpath)
    return filepath.with_name("file.json")
```